# Why did it turn out Thomas Shelby had been at the estate of the person he would find out later had lied to him?

Tags: peaky-blinders

Warning: here be spoilers of the end of the series!

---

At the end of season 6 of Peaky Blinders, in episode 6 '*Lock and Key*', Thomas Shelby retreats to the countryside in a carriage to live out the rest of his days. It is here that he learns the lethal tuberculoma he was diagnosed with was a fabrication of his fascist doctor to dispose of him as a threat to the latter's cause.

| [image: the burned newspaper Thomas picks up from the fireplace in which it is revealed his doctor, and the nurse who gave him a second opinion, were present at the wedding of the fascists Mosley and Diana in Berlin] |
| --- |

The episode then switches to said doctor in his villa, complaining about "gypsies" on his land and ordering a servant to burn their wagon.

| [image: Doctor Holford telling a servant to get rid of the "gypsy" wagon] |
| --- |
| <sup>"Go back there and set fire to the fucking thing."</sup> |

A little after the doctor is confronted by a vengeful Thomas. When Tommy returns to his site, it turns out the one the doctor's servant set on fire was actually his.

| [image: The servant about to light the carriage] |
| --- |

**How is it possible that Thomas was actually staying on the very same doctor's land during his month-long retreat?**
Is this to be regarded as an extension of the vision he had of his daughter Ruby, a vision that lead him to the discovery of his fake diagnosis, and that this gesture is symbolic for having lost his past? But then why do we see a private conversation between the doctor and his servant? Is this to be regarded as predestination?